# Application.Run(form) how to receive messages from the "form" c#

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I am stuck on understanding how after starting the message loop with Application.Run(Form) i can receive back data from the internal app.

My question is, How can I retrieve messages, objects, strings, etc? Basically I want that my internal application to send back an object to the main winform to be able to utilize the main form code to execute a USB print. Is this possible? and if it is can someone help me with a very simple example of string printText = "hello there"; and grab that onto the main winform for processing?
Sorry I know it is not the prettiest of questions, but I should be able to start from there.

My winform application is executing some legacy code of windows CE, and the data I am processing in it I need to be able to print to a USB printer.

Comment: Forms are a way to display data to a user, don't turn it into a global service system. Make service classes and singletons for that.

Comment: ok, not a problem. But I am still on the same place as before. How do I get  data back from the child form to do something with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that when you say internal app, you mean child form. so best thing to do is to create event on child form, this event will be handled by the main form. so whenever you need some data in main form then your child form can pass this data in event argument. now your main form will handle this event and to whatever with this data.

In main form

```
var childForm=new ChildForm();
childForm.DataGenerated+=DataHandler;
childForm.Show();

private void DataHandler(object data)
{
    //do something with data
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I did ended up figuring out it can work like that. The only problem is if you are passing large data in the command parameters. So for simple things it works, but if you have a large string it might hickup. We had a different solution here at work were we were able to call another class from what we call a state table, and it actually allowed me to call it from a separate project in a separate build revision (.net3.5) which actually worked to what we needed to do.